# PHP search word in string

Tags: php

I'm trying to scan a piece of text for the occurrence of certain words. If the string contains any of these words, the function should return TRUE. `in_array` can accept two arrays but it seems that all elements of the needle need to be found in the haystack for the return to be TRUE.

From the user manual - returns TRUE

```
$a = array(array('p', 'h'), array('p', 'r'), 'o');

if (in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a)) {
   return TRUE
}
```

But this doesn't return TRUE.

```
$a = array(array('p', 'h'), array('p', 'r'), 'o');

if (in_array(array('p', 'x'), $a)) {
    return TRUE
}
```

I can write the function with an if/else for every word I want to find but that seems a bit cumbersome. Is there a better way, perhaps with regex?

Background: the text I'm searching in is about 200 words max, so I explode on `" "` to make an array in which I then search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function strExists($value, $string)
{
    foreach ((array) $value as $v) {
        if (false !== strpos($string, $v)) return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a)
```

looks for an array in $a, not for two strings 'p' and 'h'. Use explode(), array_flip() and isset() instead:

```
$haystack = array_flip(explode(' ', $str));
$needles = array('p', 'h');

foreach ($needles as $needle) {
    if (isset($haystack[$needle])) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex returns TRUE if *word1*, *word2* OR *word3* is found anywhere in `$str`. No need to split the string at all and it’s case-insensitive.

```
preg_match('/word1|word2|word3/i', $str);
```

Answer (score -2):

You are missing `;` after the code `return TRUE`.